# How to delete a specific dataset from Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts

I want to add & delete datasets from chart.js using checkboxes.

Right now I am adding using this:

```
var ds1 = {
    label: ..
    data: .. etc
};
data.datasets.push(ds1);
```

When I uncheck any of the checkboxes, it's always deleting the last dataset added, which is not necessary the one of the checkbox.

I'm using `data.datasets.pop(ds1);` to remove the when a checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're removing using `data.datasets.pop(ds1)` you'll never get the result you're looking for.  The `dataset` property is an array, so let's just focus on arrays and ignore Chart.js.

First issue is that [the `pop()` method of the Arrays type does not take an argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), so providing which element you want to remove is irrelevant.  `Pop()` will always remove the last element from an array.

To remove a specific element from the array you need to use the [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function.

Let's say that `ds1` is the element you want to remove.

```
let removalIndex = data.datasets.indexOf(ds1); //Locate index of ds1
if(removalIndex >= 0) { //make sure this element exists in the array
    data.datasets.splice(removalIndex, 1);
}
```

This will delete the 1 record in the array starting at the index we located `ds1`.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at ChartJS' internal object `chart.data.datasets`, the datasets are distinguishable by the `label` you gave when initially adding the datasets (it's weird that there's no `ID`):

[image]

So it's really just a matter of filtering out an object from the array by that **Label**, and calling `chart.update();`.

```
// Filter out and set back into chart.data.datasets
chart.data.datasets = chart.data.datasets.filter(function(obj) {
    return (obj.label != targetLabel); 
});
// Repaint
chart.update();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can add an ID in your dataset :

```
var ds1 = {
    label: ..
    data: ..
    id : 'myId'
};
data.datasets.push(ds1);
```

It will not affect your dataset or your chart in anyway

Then you can find and delete (or update) :

```
data.datasets.find((dataset, index) => {
    if (dataset.id === 'myId') {
       data.datasets.splice(index, 1);
       return true; // stop searching
    }
});
myChart.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you JNYRanger!

It got like this:

```
...
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ind4').change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        graph.data.datasets.push(ds4);  
        graph.update();
    } else {
        let removalIndex = graph.data.datasets.indexOf(ds4);
        graph.data.datasets.splice(removalIndex, 1);
        graph.update();
    }
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ind5').change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        graph.data.datasets.push(ds5);  
        graph.update();
    } else {
        let removalIndex = graph.data.datasets.indexOf(ds5);
        graph.data.datasets.splice(removalIndex, 1);
        graph.update();
    }
});
```

I just added `graph.data....` (when graph is the var of my chart) and `graph.update()` by the end of every action.